# Entreprise Library through nuget cant find Database Trace Listener

Tags: nuget

I started to use nuget to include EL in projects, and I came across a problem that I cannot resolve.

I included the Logging and Data Access Application Block, but the Database Trace Listener of the Logging Block is not present.

I tried searching for another nuget packet the would contain that listener but to no avail.

Any sugestions?

Thanks